# Running gitlab pipelines before a merge request is published

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project that runs a pipeline with a few jobs/stages in it. I have the project set up to create merge requests when I push to another branch. Those jobs kick off *after* the merge request is published. Is there any way to start the pipeline *before* the merge request is published?

EDIT

Here is what I ended up adding based on the accepted answer.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - when: always
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the basic configuration, I'd probably take a look at `workflow:rules` in Gitlab's [pipeline configuration reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules):

> The top-level `workflow:` keyword determines whether or not a pipeline is created. It accepts a single `rules:` keyword that is similar to `rules:` defined in jobs. Use it to define what can trigger a new pipeline.

Here you could use the `merge_request_event`-rule:

> For pipelines created when a merge request is created or updated. Required to enable merge request pipelines, merged results pipelines, and merge trains.

Gitlab also offers [Pipelines for merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/), which could be a better fit for your specific use-case. Keep in mind that not every user can trigger a pipeline if the relevant branch is protected.